# Automated rosbag on start up

Tags: ros, rosbag, ubuntu, startup, odroid

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My plan is to use a remote computer to create a rosbag.
I was wondering what is the best practice to automatically start a rosbag record instance after boot on an Ubuntu 14.04 Odroid system. Any experiences ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237241/automated-rosbag-on-start-up/) by [Sebastian Rockel](https://answers.ros.org/users/1966/sebastian-rockel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2016-06-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have done that using systemd services that launches a roslaunch file from a bash script.
You can also do it using the ubuntu's "startup applications" or "sessions" to launch any app at startup.

In any case, be careful with rosbag files because they are really disk space consuming.

---

Originally posted by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) with karma: 2982 on 2016-06-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sebastian Rockel](https://answers.ros.org/users/1966/sebastian-rockel/) on 2016-06-18**:
Thanks for the pointer. I eventually got it working with Upstart instead of Systemd since it was used on my system.

**Comment by [Andre_Preller_3000](https://answers.ros.org/users/26157/andre_preller_3000/) on 2016-10-03**:
I just migrated my project to Ubuntu 16.04LTS and need to get Systemd to do exactly what you're describing Pablo, could you possibly post an example bash script here? Cheers